# Creating Group/Teams in Django - Py

Tags: python, django

I am having difficulty finding examples, applications for group creation on Django, and could use some help.

Basically there's a 'Create a New Team' page where the logged in user can use, I am trying to auto-assign the user to the group with `.user_set.add(User).`

My questions are:
***Am I creating the new teams correctly*** (when I debug, g1 gets overwritten each time, should I do a For Loop to make sure g+n=? doesn't exist?
and
***Any way to access the created teams*** in the admin page or the Django Py Shell?

Thanks in advance, I'm a beginner

**models.py**

```
class TeamCreation(models.Model):
    class meta:
        db_table="teams"

    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    team_key = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.team_name
```

**forms.py**

```
class TeamCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TeamCreation
        fields=['team_name','team_key']
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import TeamCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from .models import TeamCreation

@login_required
def create_team(request):

        if request.POST:
            form = TeamCreationForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                newTeam = form.save(commit=False)
                newTeam.author = request.user
                newTeam.date_posted = timezone.now

                newTeam.save()

                #set group name
                g1 = Group.objects.create(name=newTeam.team_name)

                #autopopulate / assign author to new team
                g1.user_set.add(newTeam.author)

                #debug (hopefully print: Team Name, Key, Creator, Members
                print(newTeam)

        else:
            form=TeamCreationForm()

        context={
                "form":form,
                }

        return render(request, "pages/team_creation.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> g1 gets overwritten each time, should I do a For Loop to make sure g+n=? doesn't exist

It's being overwritten (created) each time because you didn't check if group with this name already exists. Try this:

```
new_group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name=newTeam.team_name)
```

> Any way to access the created teams in the admin page

Yes, in `admin.py` add this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from app.models import TeamCreation

admin.site.register(TeamCreation)
```

Just change `from app.model` to your actual app name.

You can read more about [Django admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects) here.

Also, I don't know whats your goal regarding to group creation, but maybe it'll be useful for you to read about [group permission](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#programmatically-creating-permissions).